# Struct no seeing its content?

Tags: swift, struct

So i am trying to get the data,

```
struct  Location: Decodable {
    var elevation = String()
    var id = String()
    var latitude = String()
    var longitude = String()
    var name = String()
    var region = String()
    var unitaryAuthArea = String()
     }

struct  Locations: Decodable {
    var Location :[Location]
}


struct Weather: Decodable{
    var Locations :[Locations]
}
```

inside these, however, for some reason, when i use this line

```
  let withoutElevation = weather.Locations.Location.filter {$0.elevation == nil}
```

i can't get an error that LOCATIONS doest have LOCATION. any ideas why?

Comment: Your coding experience will be improved if you follow the standard that variable names should start with lowercase letters. Struct/class names start with uppercase letters. So the line `var Locations : [Locations]` should be `var locations: [Locations]`. Same for some others.

Comment: Note to others: This is a great learning opportunity. I tried to point OP in the right direction, and hopefully he progress from there. Please don't spoil the answer right away

Comment: @DamianTalaga Your `Location` by default has an Elevation of `""`, a lat/long of `""`, etc, and all of them are mutable (the lat and long of a location can change? That's strange). That doesn't make much sense, does it? You can better model this with more appropriate data types (e.g  a `CLLocation` for the `lat`/`long`/`elevation`), narrowing down the mutability (`let` instead of `var`), and not providing non-sensical defaults for all values (don't default everything to `String()`)

Comment: @Alexander You should put that comment on your answer.

Comment: @rmaddy Done. Sometimes it's a good thing to be redundant, because redundancy can be good, sometimes.

Comment: @Alexander I am getting the data from the website so i have to use lat/long/elev for now

Comment: @DamianTalaga You can just write a custom [`init(from decoder :Decoder)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable/2894081-init) that converts from the raw `String` values the API provides, to the sensible data types you would like to use in the rest of your application. Don't let one data source's design decisions taint your entire code base

Answer (score 0):

This can be better understood by examining the types that are in play at every stage of this "chain".

```
let withoutElevation = weather // Weather
    .Locations // [Locations]
    .Location // doesn't exist, but Location was intended
    .filter {$0.elevation == nil} // invalid, but [Location] was intended
```

At that point, the error becomes clear. `weather.Locations` is a `[Locations]`, which doesn't have a `Location` member. What you actually wanted was to get all of the `Location`s within the `Locations` struct.

Knowing this, take another stab at it, and see how much further you can get. Let me know if you have further questions

***Note to others:*** This is a great learning opportunity. I tried to point OP in the right direction, and hopefully he progress from there. Please don't spoil the answer right away

Comment: thanks, hat is exactly what i thought, i have just no idea why if before i specified that locations has location so no idea whats wrong there

Comment: @DamianTalaga I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment, at all. Could you elaborate?

Comment: i Locations already has Location inside as an object, so i have no idea why it is not seen

Comment: @DamianTalaga `Locations` ***does*** have a `Location` member, yes, but `[Locations]` (a.k.a. `Array<Locations>`) ***doesn't***.

Comment: Omg you are absolutely right, thank you, that was so stupid